# How to render Dijit widgets?

Tags: javascript, widget, dojo

I am trying to render Dijit widgets without success. For example, I would like to create a toolbar:

```
var tb = new dijit.Toolbar({
});

tb.addChild(new dijit.MenuItem({
label: 'test'
}));

tb.placeAt(document.getElementById('menu'));

tb.startup();
```

Based on the documentation, there are no render, etc methods available. How am I supposed to render it or any other widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

placeAt() "renders" the widget by placing its DOM node somewhere on the page.  I think you're supposed to call startup() before you do that, though.

(Incidentally, you can just pass the ID to placeAt(); the call to getElementById() is unnecessary.)